# WSO2 API Manager - context management

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Can we reuse the context of an api that has been deleted? I am looking at the scenario, where someone accidentally deleted the api and want to recreate it. Or reuse the context for different purpose.

Currently, when I try do the same, I get an error - Error occurred while adding the API. A duplicate API already exists for "your api"

Is this a bug?

Comment: What is the version of the API Manager you are using? Deleted from the publisher?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to case when deleted from publisher. version 1.6.

Comment: I just tried deleting and adding the api with the same context, and it didn't allow me. May be I should try in after installing newer version and see if it has the same behavior.

Comment: I have the same bug in Version 2.1.0. Deleted through Publisher, but when I try to recreate using the store Api, it fails with a duplicate api message.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use. But i think there is a reported bug regarding this.(not sure though) We will fix in the future release. But please, create a jira with all details.So, we wont miss it..

Answer (score 0):

I delete and create new API's with the same name with both 1.6 and 1.7 and have no issue.